# php generate a string and check from mysql with not exist

Tags: php, mysql, shuffle

I want to generate a string to post a url. Then make the post url like: `http://www.mydomain.com/post/afCeYk`, and store this url in the mysql. In order to avoid a repeat `url` , I think first should check the mysql whether the `url` has already existed. In my code, I just check once, I can not ensure the second generate string hasn't already existed. So how do I make a loop?

```
$shufstr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$rdstr = substr(str_shuffle($shufstr),0,6);
$query =  mysql_query("select * from table where post_url = '".$rdstr."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    //insert the url rules into db  
}else{
    //generate a new string and check the db again  
}
```

Comment: How to make a loop? Seriously? Did you search? Anyway it's a bad appoach - it will get slower and slower as the URLs are consumed. Use an autoincrement ID unless you need the URL to be hard to guess.

Comment: My suggestion is to add an unique key to your column to really prevent the duplicates.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should query the database once to collect all of the data from the table, then generate a string and check it against the array you get.

As opposed to querying the database over and over, this has a performance benefit.

(not actual code)

```
$url_list = query("SELECT `post_url` FROM `table`");
do {
    $random_string = generate_random_string();
}
while(!in_array($random_string, $url_list));
```

In addition, make sure no duplicate is entered by making the column **[`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)**.

Comment: This would work, but may result in a huge array depending upon the number of records in the DB.

Comment: Since you still need to compare your value against all others, there's really no way around it. Besides, it beats looping the same query over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop, but it would get pretty slow after you have a few thousand URLs saved:

```
$shufstr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$validString=false;
while(!$validString){
    $rdstr = substr(str_shuffle($shufstr),0,6);
    $query =  mysql_query("select * from table where post_url = '".$rdstr."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){ //This is also different from your code as you don't want to do the insert if there is 1+ row with that url. 
        $validString=true;
        //insert the url rules into db  
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid looping queries, the cost is high especially when you have the query reload with each iteration.  You should at least put the query before the loop, then loop the queries result.

Comment: Inefficient. Would cause massive slowdown once he reaches the hundreds/thousands.

Answer (score 1):

If it were my project, I would add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the post_url column itself, this will ensure that no duplicates will be entered from any point of entry (app, command line, etc). More info on [MySQL unique](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html).

Comment: But it would blow up if it someone does try to enter a duplicate, other than trying to generate a different one.

Comment: @Truth: Agreed. However handling unique constraints at the database layer ensure consistency no matter the point of access. For this req, he would have to issue the select or handle the error thrown due to unique constraint failure.